# Atomic Compare Operator (No swap)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am looking for a comparator operator that can be used to compare two atomic variable atomically under C++11. Here i do not want to swap values stored under these atomic objs so i am not interested in compare_and_swap functions.
Please refer example below:

```
std::atomic<uint32_t> readIdx{0};
std::atomic<uint32_t> writeIdx{0};

while(writeIdx + 1 == readIdx)   <<<<------------------
{
     std::this_thread::yield();
}
```

All i want, to make code represented with arrow line to be atomic. Is it possible?
If not, does `writeIdx == readIdx` is an atomic operation?

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic" here? Precisely what sequence of evaluations this code may observe that you want to prevent? The condition is equivalent to `writeIdx.load() + 1 == readIdx.load()`. The two `load()` calls are atomic, of course; the rest acts on plain `uint32_t`s.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: If there is another thread in the system, it may change `writeIdX` after the OP's thread reads it, and before it reads `readIdx`.  In this case, the OP seems to want the two `load()` calls to execute atomically *as a group*, and not for each individual `load()` to be atomic (which they apparently are).

Comment: @NathanFellman: How would this differ in observable behavior from the situation where `writeIdx` is changed right after both atomics are loaded? The end result is exactly the same, so why would one want to prevent one case but not the other?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You could find yourself in a position where you read the values at times that are very far apart, and get invalid results.  

I'm assuming that this is a very simplistic example, so it could be that even if it's harmless in this case, a more general case should be protected.

Comment: @NathanFellman Still, you won't be able to establish the concept of both atomics being _equal at the same time_ without introducing an additional lock. The problem is that whatever code depends on that condition needs to be part of the same atomic block of execution that performs the check (otherwise it might change before the code finishes executing). On the other hand, if no part of the code depends on the condition, it makes no sense to introduce it as a concept in the first place.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: I agree, and that should be the answer to this question.  I was answering Igor's questions about the need for atomicity and what it means in this case.

Comment: @NathanFellman: what do you mean by "invalid results"? What exactly constitutes a "valid result"? There is no concept of "time" in the C++ memory model, only "order of evaluations" - and there isn't necessarily a single total order.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: In this case a "valid result" could be, for instance, that `ReadIdx < WriteIdx`.  Any other result could be invalid.  You're right that the concept of time isn't defined in C++.  That is why you need additional concepts like atomicity to help the programmer enforce concepts of time, that are made manifest by changes in the order of evaluations.

Comment: @NathanFellman: this is circular reasoning - you are defining the result of evaluation of one comparison of atomics in terms of another comparison of atomics. The condition `ReadIdx < WriteIdx` should hold when evaluated how?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: (Keep in mind that I'm merely building an example in my mind based on the scant details in the question).  Let's assume that the condition `ReadIdx < WriteIdx` must always hold, otherwise the code doesn't make sense.  It could be that this condition does in fact always hold, but if the SW reads one of these variables, then another thread updates them both, and SW reads the other variable, then this condition may not hold as far as the SW is concerned.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Consider the case when `WriteIdx + 1 != ReadIdx`, and in fact `WriteIdx == ReadIdx`.  `WriteIdx` is read, then `ReadIdx` is incremented by some other thread, then `ReadIdx` is read by the current thread.  In this case, should you want the current thread to `yield()`?

Comment: @NathanFellman: what does it mean that "the condition `ReadIdx < WriteIdx` holds"? If it means "the expression `ReadIdx < WriteIdx` must always evaluate to `true`" then we are right back where we started - arguing about an expression whose value is unspecified. If it means "holds at any given point in time", then that is meaningless since there's no concept of "point in time" in C++. Similarly, when you say "the case when `WriteIdx + 1 != ReadIdx`", what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: And that is exactly why OP wants it to be atomic!

Comment: @NathanFellman: you seem to be using the word "atomic" in a sense different from that assigned to it by the standard, namely "1.10/5 **The library defines** a number of atomic operations..." (emphasis mine.) You can't make something atomic - it either is or it isn't. You can impose a *happens-before* relationship on certain evaluations by using appropriate synchronization mechanisms - is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You can make something atomic by wrapping some sort of locking mechanism around it, for instance/

Comment: @NathanFellman: what is "something" in this sentence? Again, you can't make anything atomic - not in the formal sense of the term. However, you can, for example, ensure that any modifications to `writeIdx` and `readIdx` either happen-before the two loads, or happen-after them (in other words, there is no modification that happens-between them or is unsynchronized with either of them). I suspect that's what you mean, informally, by "make atomic". To achieve that, of course, it's not enough to wrap the two loads into a lock - all modifications would have to be performed under that same lock.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: judging by the text of the question, it seems obvious to me that the OP is asking about how to perform an operation atomically in the informal sense you mention, and not in the formal sense.  I agree that it is not trivial to do so, because it would require each and every write to these variables to be performed under a lock.

Comment: Here my worries were (with 'writeIdx + 1 == readIdx') , what if writeIdx got loaded but before readIdx can be loaded on register before that this thread may get preempted and then this while statement would be redundant and we may write/read on wrong place (or yeild inappropriately since witrIdx might now have old value compare to readIdx). since we have atomic compare and swap so i though we might have atomic compare or some hack to get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible, since it would not make any sense.

Your code will obtain valid values for the comparison, but it gives very little guarantees on when those values are obtained. So if the check succeeds, all you'll know is that `readIdx` was at some point in time equal to a value that `writeIdx + 1` yielded at some point in time. These two points in time are mostly unrelated. In particular, it is allowed that at no single point in time the value of `readIdx` was equal to the value of `writeIdx + 1` but still the check succeeds.

Here's why this is not really a problem: You won't be able to establish the concept of both atomics being *equal at the same time* without introducing an additional lock. The problem is that whatever code depends on that condition needs to be part of the same atomic block of execution that performs the check. If it is not, the condition might change before the code finishes executing.

On the other hand, if no part of the code depends on the condition, it makes no sense to introduce it as a concept in the first place.

So here's how to continue: Go back and reevaluate whether you really have code that depends on the condition that both variables have to have the expected values at the time that code executes. If that is a case, you'll need to protect that code with a lock. If not, it is likely that you don't need to check the condition at all, as the guarantees given by your current code are probably too weak to be of any real use.

Comment: "If not, you are probably fine with your current code" ... though one then can't help but wonder why you would want to perform the (largely meaningless) check in the first place. It's not much different from tossing a coin at this point.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Good point, the overall value of that check is indeed questionable.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: as you yourself point out, this requirement is necessary  in order to avoid the case that you wrote, where, "it is allowed that at no single point in time the value of `readIdx` was equal to the value of `writeIdx + 1` but still the check succeeds.  The point is that it's probably not as trivial as the OP was hoping.

Comment: Well, i am not a time traveler, even if i can i would probably be fine with that. I am fine if readIdx and writeIdx 'BOTH' are loaded atomically with ech other. Code (and other threads) would be fine with that as well, as no wrong doing will be done. My problem is what if writeIdx is read first and then that thread get preempted not when that thread starts it would have wrong value of writeIdx to compare with readIdx. that will lead to problem.

Comment: Accepting this ans as the answer to my original question is NO.